# Redirect users to a page specific to their account on sign in

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, redirect

I am trying to set up a user login database and page and have it work that when a user signs in, it authenticates their login details and if they are correct, have it redirect them to a page I've set up specifically for their account. There is no account creation page or anything, I will add users details directly into the database as it is for a client system where I can link in design work and final artwork files for clients into their own page that can be accessed once they're logged in.

I don't know exactly how to set this up. My previous system (which I am upgrading), would present clients to a page to select their client code from a drop-down list which redirected them to a login page specific to their account and the login details were hardcoded into the PHP page, no database for user credentials. I really want to upgrade this system and streamline it to only have one login page and credentials stored securely in a database.

Any tips/support are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understood from your question, you are asking about the whole system instead of an specific part of it, you wanna know how to set up the whole system, am I right?
if yes, then this is the steps I would go through:

1- you need this data to be secured and not easily exposed or hacked. so you can choose a framework like laravel which would do a lot of steps for you.(Actually the authentication is a built in which you can set up in 10 sec)

2-since it's an art website (I guess) and each artist might request a completely different design of their page your should also gaurd each page so an artist can't edit another artist's page. it's very simple but you have no idea how many websites i have seen that the moment you log in you can edit or at least see other user's dashboard.

3- but if the pages are not soo diferent your data needs to be dynamic not hard coded in each page.so you would design one page but all the section would be dynamically added.

I don't know if I could help, but if you have any question that I am capable of answering i would be happy to help